# Starting the car

Tags: starting, ignition, key

I just bought a new Honda Civic 2018 LX, and I was wondering:

When inserting the key into the ignition, should I wait on the ON position until the lights settle before starting the engine?

Comment: No reason to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Agree with @Moab here ... no reason to wait. Just fire the thing up.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Also, can I leave the AC on when turning off the car? So the next time I start the car, the AC is already on

Answer (score 1):

You can just start it directly, unless it is a diesel when you need to allow time for the heater plugs to cycle - 5 to 10 seconds when cold.

If the engine is already warm enough then that heating time may be ignored as well.